# Function in SQL Server 2008 to put single quotes around each element of a list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that is receiving as a parameter a list of values to include in a query. For example `NY, NJ, CT, PA`

In my dynamic SQL query in the stored procedure, I want to select records

```
WHERE state IN ('NY', 'NJ', 'CT', 'PA').
```

If I use the parameter as it gets to the SP, I would be doing

```
WHERE state IN 'NY, NJ, CT, PA'.
```

Therefore, I need to convert

```
'NY, NJ, CT, PA'
```

to

```
('NY','NJ','CT','PA').
```

Is there a function to do that?

Thanks!

Hey, I think Kevin pointed in the right direction here. All I need to do is:

```
WHERE state IN REPLACE(('NY, NJ, CT, PA'), ',' , ''',''')
```

Or, since I really have it in a variable...

```
WHERE state IN REPLACE ((@StateList), ',' , ''',''')
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5986/Passing-a-Comma-Delimited-Parameter-to-a-Stored-Pr

Comment: You say its a dynamic query? so is `WHERE state in ..` etc in a string already?

Comment: Do you have any control of how the data is passed to the stored proc?

Comment: If you have flexibility to change your stored procedure, try `where patindex('%'+state+'%', 'NY, NJ, CT, PA') > 0` instead of `WHERE state IN ('NY', 'NJ', 'CT', 'PA')`. Otherwise, use a user-defined function to build a list from your string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fun way to do it without a function:

```
DECLARE @StateList VARCHAR(50)='NY, NJ, CT, PA' --(substitute for your parameter)
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ',' + REPLACE(@StateList,' ','') + ',' LIKE '%,' + State + ',%'
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks a lot. You gave me the idea. I think all I have to do is REPLACE ',' for ''','''.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, @Amarundo, I guess I missed that this was a Dynamic SQL query you were doing.  Glad my suggestion still helped, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  One simple way would be to insert them to a temp table (e.g. @temp_states) and do this:

```
WHERE state in (SELECT state from @temp_states)
```

Instead of inserting them to a table, you can use a function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco) to generate the table for you:

```
WHERE state in (SELECT * from dbo.Split(',', 'NY,NJ,CT,PA'))
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple option is to do:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX ( CONCAT (', ', state,',') ,  CONCAT (', ', @PARAM,',')) > 0
```

Comment: You might want to modify that. As-is, it would have issues with the spaces in between the states.

Comment: In addition to what Kevin said, there will be issues with the first and the last entries on the list.

Comment: Thanks, didn't spot the spaces.